# how to print the value of a pointer from a structure

Tags: c

The value contained in the pointer 'p' from the structure below is wrong printed and i can not find the way to print it right. What's the right code for it?
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct my_struct{ //structure definition
    int a,*p;
};

int main(){

    my_struct var;
    var.a = 5;                  //variable definition
    var.p = &(var.a);           //pointer gets address from variable
    printf("%d\n",var.p);       // the number 2686744 is printed instead of the number '5'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dereference it with `*var.p`...

Comment: The pointer itself is just an address.  You want the value it points to, so you need to dereference it with the `*` operator, i.e. `*var.p`  You can also remove the parentheses in `&(var.a)` and instead just use `&var.a`, which is much more standard.

Comment: Note also that `.` has higher precedence than unary dereference `*` (_not_ multiply!) so the parentheses in others' suggestions of `*(var.p)` are strictly optional and for readers who think it offers added clarity (or can't be bothered memorising precedence rules ;-). As Tom's comment indicates, the same is true for `.` versus `&`.

Comment: Quick note. Because your struct is not `typedef`'d, you need to declare it with `struct my_struct var;`. Just a side note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier to `printf` expects an `int`, but you're passing it an `int *`.

You need to dereference the pointer to obtain an `int`:

```
printf("%d\n",*(var.p));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the literal address of the pointer (i.e. not the value it points to, but the address in memory of where it points) when you write `printf("%d\n", var.p)`.  To access the value pointed to you need to dereference the pointer with `printf("%d\n", *(var.p))`.

As a side note: if you ever do want to access the address of a pointer for whatever reason in a `printf` family function, use the `%p` format specifier instead: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1):

You're not dereferencing the pointer

```
my_struct var;
var.a = 5;                  
var.p = &(var.a);           
printf("%d\n",*(var.p)); //this will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *var.p at print to dereference the pointer p and get it's value. Right now you are printing the memory location in decimal.

Comment: `var` is not a pointer, so you can't use `->`. (not my down-vote)

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer var.p is simply **containing** an address. When i say containing, i mean it's value is an address.
In your case, this is the var.a's address.
When you try to print its **value**, you will print the var.a's address.

If you want to print what is **CONTAINED** at this address, or what is the **VALUE** at this address, you have to put a star before it.

In your case, you do not want to print var.p's **value**, as this an address, but you want to print the **value contained** at this address, using *(var.p).

Take care, there may be a difference in some languages between "*var.p" and "*(var.p)".
Imagine these operations in mathematics : (2x3)² and 2x3².
On the first operation, the ² will affect the whole multiplication, when, in the second operation, the ² will only affect the number 3.

In fact, you may want to try it by yourself to know how the language you are using work, *var.p may give you a way different result :)
However, using parenthesis in this case is a good practice, even if the language does give the same result.

PS : Just an extra information, if you ever need to print an address (which is not your case at the moment, you only want to print a decimal) using printf, replace %d by %p.

Comment: The extra information about the operators precedence is just misleading, as it doesn't apply here. `*(var.p)` is the same as `*var.p` because `.` has a higher precedence than `*`.